# knitr: Add figure notes in .Rmd file

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I have a series of .png images that I would like to add notes to in an Rmarkdown document that I am knitting to a .pdf. The basic code for each image looks like this:

````
```{r certs_coefplot, out.width="100%", fig.cap=fig.4_cap}
knitr::include_graphics("certs_coefplot.png")
```
````

With beamer slides, I have just inserted some basic latex like this:

```
\tiny \emph{Notes}: Put Notes here \normalsize
```

below each code chunk.

But if I try this in the context of a larger document, the notes do not appear below the figure.

A solution involving a custom hook was proposed to a similar question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047072/knitr-add-figure-notes) about adding notes to figures in an .Rnw file. In particular, the version where you put the code for the hook at the beginning and then write:

```
notes = "Notes to explain the plot"
sources = "Explain the sources"
```

in each chunk seems really convenient.

Is it possible to apply a similar solution an RMarkdown file?